# Translation needed for www.mirrored.to api php code to python

Tags: python, php, curl, post, python-requests

```
<?php

//***EDIT THE FOLLOWING ***//
$api_key = "abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdef";  //Your API Key
//***EDIT END ***//

$url = "https://www.mirrored.to/api/v1/get_account_info";
$post = array(
    'api_key' => $api_key
    );
$res = curl($url,$post);
unset($post);
$res = json_decode($res,true);
if($res['status'] === true) {
print_r($res['message']);
    }
else{
echo $res['message'];
}

function curl($link, $postfields = '')
{
    $ch = curl_init($link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
    if ($postfields) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    }
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    return ($page);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

above is the php code example by mirrored.to api, because my project is in python, i tried to replicate  curl request using pycurl. my code so far.

```
    url = "https://www.mirrored.to/api/v1/get_account_info"
    apikey = "e51514aeb48ef5334f85718fe4b3a15b"
    crl = pycurl.Curl()
    import certifi
    crl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
    crl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
    crl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json' , 'Accept: application/json'])
    query = json.dumps({'api_key': apikey})
    crl.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    crl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, query)
    crl.perform()
```

response is {"status":false,"message":"No valid API key provided!"}
i tried  requests.post auth method to post api key but doesnt work
any help is appreciated, the people over at mirrored.to cant help me, they just say they don't do python.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `https://www.mirrored.to/api/v1/get_account_info` is a GET request, and to authenticate you it to pass the APIKEY as a param so the below code is faulty in your above implementation:

```
query = json.dumps({'api_key': apikey})
crl.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
crl.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, query)
```

Instead you should pass the apikey as below:

```
params = {'api_key': apikey}
crl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params))
```

So your overall code will look like

```
url = "https://www.mirrored.to/api/v1/get_account_info"
apikey = "e51514aeb48ef5334f85718fe4b3a15b"
crl = pycurl.Curl()
import certifi
crl.setopt(pycurl.CAINFO, certifi.where())
params = {'api_key': apikey}
crl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params))
crl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: application/json' , 'Accept: application/json'])
crl.perform()
```

Comment: hi nishant, i just tried the above code, still returns the status false no valid api key provided... many thanks for your reply.... oh the api documentation says API Path
Current API version is v1. All requests should be sent over HTTPS. All methods are done using POST unless otherwise stated. any way to pass params using POST instead of GET

Comment: Hi, nishant, i can close this, thanks to your urlencode, i just pass it as postfields and it is working now.

Comment: @MurphyKwok please mark it as the answer and make any corrections if needed, so that it will be helpful for others